# AT&T VPN blocks incomming tcp connections

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, windows-firewall

I got this [VPN client from AT&T](https://www.corp.att.com/agnc/windows/) that I need to connect to some network. VPN itself still works fine, but it blocks all incoming TCP connections from my local network. It look like it uses the windows firewall for this and prevents me from accessing the control panel.

The computer hosted by virtualbox on my local machine. The blocked connection is coming from the host system.

And how can I unblock this?

Comment: yes, I tried solving this with AT&T support. Got me nowhere.

Comment: Incoming TCP connections from where? Do you have a public IP or how do they come in? What do routing tables state?

Comment: On most VPNS the admins of the VPN server (in your case the admins of "some network") can decide what traffic they allow or deny: they create a policy that the VPN client applies for being able to connect to the VPN server. On common policy is limit all connections to those that come through the VPN. If that is a problem you have to talk to the admins of the VPN server (admins of "some network").

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the feedback. Question is how does it work? And how can I hack it? It would help to see what ports are blocked.

Comment: For maximum security, some VPN clients can do "full tunnel" mode, where ALL traffic to or from the VPN client machine MUST go via the VPN tunnel. Sometimes this is a setting you can control locally on the VPN client, but sometimes this is dictated by the VPN server (the VPN admin requires you to use a VPN client that allows him to force you to use full tunnel mode).